# Can you access parent object fields in a 'New' page override without using SOQL?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I have two objects, `Parent__c` and `Child__c`, `Child__c` has a lookup field to `Parent__c` called`ParentId__c`.

I have overridden the **New** and **Edit** pages for `Child__c` using a Visualforce page with the `Child__c` standard controller.

```
<apex:page standardController="Child__c" extension="ParentChildExtension">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Child__c.ParentId**r.Name}"/>
</apex:page>
```

If I click the **Edit** button on the `Child__c` related list to access my page, the `apex:sectionHeader` title is populated. However when I use the **New** button it is not.

I've tried using the `addFields` method in my controller to add the `Name` (and other fields) from `Parent__c` that I'm interested in but this still does not work when using the **New** button.

---

## Edit Button Behaviour

[image: Edit Button - Related List]

**Visualforce Page**
[image: Edit Button - Visualforce Page]

---

## New Button Behaviour

[image: New Button - Related List]

**Visualforce Page**
[image: New Button - Visualforce Page]

---

This is easily solved by querying for the `Name` field of `Parent__c` in a controller extension (if it's missing), but is there a way of doing this that **without** using a controller extension and/or a SOQL query (and preferably without resorting to the "lkid hack" mentioned in [Keith C's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/30371/5460))?

```
public with sharing class ParentChildExtension
{
    private final Child__c child;

    private String parentName;

    public ParentChildExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        this.child = (Child__c)stdController.getRecord();
        this.parentName = child.ParentId**r.Name;
    }

    public String getParentName()
    {
        if(parentName == null)
        {
            parentName = [SELECT Name FROM Parent__c WHERE Id = :child.ParentId__c].Name;
        }

        return parentName;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Added stipulation that I would prefer to avoid the "lkid hack" if possible, and that I've tried using the `addFields` method in my controller.

Comment: In a 'New' you must query specifically for the parent.  The object brought back from the 'New' button is not in the database, which also means that the links to the parent is not yet in the database.  It still has time to change before actually being inserted and so makes sense that it doesn't have the parent value by default.  You must query to get the value.

Answer (score 5):

The standard controller [addFields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) method supports field access via relationship fields allowing you to pass the responsibility back to the standard controller to do the querying. But "New" behaving differently to "Edit" suggests that the problem may be more related to differences in how the standard controller handles the two situations. But addFields is worth a quick try.

Beyond that, you'll note some command-line parameters get automatically added that identify the id and name of the parent object. (Google "Lkid hack" for more detail.) As you don't care about the specific key values, you can just grab the id and name from there.

**PS** But as the comment thread below discusses, given the choice between an extra query and relying on Salesforce not changing the URL pattern, the extra query is the way to go. Meanwhile, a load more votes and comments on https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE for the benefit of future generations can't do any harm.

Comment: I should have added to my post that I've tried addFields and that doesn't work. The problem I have with the "Lkid hack" is that it requires an awful lot of work to get it going without hard-coding field IDs, and that makes it feel like a worse solution than the extension and SOQL one.

Comment: ... I'm suggesting you can rely on the pattern not the actual values e.g. find the key that ends in "lkid" then pull out the field id from that then take the value that has that key. Relies on the URL pattern that Salesforce reserves the right to change (but many people use) but doesn't rely on the field ids.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, but my overall opinion remains, whilst this does avoid the need for an extension and SOQL query, it still feel like a bit of a hack, especially as it's vulnerable to being broken if SFDC decide to change how their URLs are formed in future releases. I'll give you an up-vote regardless, since hacky as the answer is, it does answer my question.

Comment: I'm not denying it is a hack and for the sake of avoiding a query I wouldn't use it. The URL pattern is more necessary in other cases and an alternative from salesforce remains in the safe harboured (and probably distant) future https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gM7mAAE.

Comment: Just to confirm, this only works for the 'Name' field (or whichever field is used in the lookup depending on the object) and won't work other arbitrary fields as these are passed in the URL. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, when using "New" from the detail list the only parent value the child always needs is the parent id (and name where the parent can be edited via its name). I didn't think anything else was passed in this case.

Comment: I agree entirely with this comment thread, and Keith's answer.. the controller extension and SOQL query is by far the best route to take. addFields won't work in this scenario (been there myself!) and relying on the URL pattern just to avoid a simple DB query in this rather specific scenario is too risky. Answer upvoted.