# Including a Master Record in a $Action.Custom_Object.New

Tags: visualforce

I have a button on a Visualforce page defined as:

`<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Object__c.New)}" value="New Detail"/>`

The page it is on uses the standard controller of the parent object. I want this button to send the user to a page with the parent object already filled in, rather than have the user select. I know I can use URL parameters to do it, but I'd have to change the parameters for it to work in different orgs. Basically, I want the button to function just like the New button does on the related list.

Comment: This is very similar to my question here (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/can-you-access-parent-object-fields-in-a-new-page-override-without-using-soql) where I basically got the answer that it can't be done... (yet).

Comment: can you try using a custom setting/ label and ask the admin of the org to update the value as part of install ( maybe a little technical for a basic admin to do)

Comment: I really want it to be an automatic process. I'd probably use a field describe before creating a custom setting, except field describes don't give you IDs. Grrr.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to programmatically generate this URL using [Andy Fawcett's Querying Custom Object and Field IDs via Tooling API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/).